# Access 2002 - display text on form

Tags: ms-access, expression

I have asked two similar questions, neither of which have been written with the necessary precision I need, but both of which have been answered correctly. I apologise for this and I will attempt to ask the question again with suitable precision.

I have a form on which I am attempting to display information from several tables. The form is called `contacts1`. The main database table the form is based on is a customer table called `contacts`, and is keyed on `contact_id`. I use the form to display information relating to a `contact`. I want to also display the address of a contact (in a text field called `concatAddress`). The address information is in a database table called `address`, keyed on `address_id`, and has a foreign key relationship with the `contacts` table via `contact_id`.

I have an expression I am trying to use to display the address: `=DLookUp(" [address]![address_line_1] & [address]![ address_line_2] & [address]![city]","[concatAddress]","[address]![contact_id]=" & [Forms]![contacts1]![contact_id])`. This gives me an `#Error` on my form. I am unsure what is causing this error.

Why would my expression cause the error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear. I have the answer: I forgot to include the table the address data is coming from - I mistook the table name field for the field the data is going into. So, this works:

`=DLookUp("address_line_1 &" "& address_line_2 &" "& city","[address]","[address]![contact_id]=" & Forms!contacts1!contact_id)` (I added spaces between the address fields and the city).

I hope this helps someone - I've been playing with this for a while now.